# More recently published comprehensive reference on inequalities in the spirit of Hardy-Littlewood-Pólya

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question, inequalities

Is there a *comprehensive* reference book on **inequalities** in the
spirit of the one written by G.H. Hardy, J.E. Littlewood, and G. Pólya<sup>**(*)**</sup>, but more ***up-to-date*** (i.e., published in *more recent years* and with both well-established results and *novel developments*)?

---

<sup>**(*)**</sup> **Clarification**

The following description is taken from the publisher's website:

> "This classic of the mathematical literature forms a **comprehensive
>   study of the inequalities used throughout mathematics**. First published
>   in 1934, it presents **clearly and lucidly** both the **statement and proof
>   of all the standard inequalities of analysis**. The authors were
>   well-known for their powers of exposition and made this subject
>   accessible to a wide audience of mathematicians."

Comment: How about "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class" by J. Michael Steele, Cambridge University Press 2004?

Comment: @Stopple, I've heard of it, but I'm not sure that it is at the same level as the book mentioned above. Do you have any information?

Comment: Would anyone explain why this is "primarily opinion based"? I honestly don't get it.

Comment: Another useful reference is Mitrinovic's monograph *Analytic inequalities*. https://books.google.com/books?id=m0Z_MQEACAAJ&dq=editions%3A8T7Rhyr-88IC&source=gbs_book_other_versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the following book is a very nice 'grandson' of the one written by Hardy, Littlewood, and Pólya:

> D.J.H. GARLING, *Inequalities. A Journey into Linear Analysis*,
>   Cambridge University Press, 2007.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you add to your answer some information about this book and a brief description?

Comment: The book is by: "D. J. H. Garling" and not Ben Garling. It's a really nice book though.

Comment: Dear @Suvrit, could you add some comments on this book?

Comment: @Dal: please have a look at it here: https://books.google.com/books?id=j7JYneuaCxQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=garling&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fFn_VPfJFoyRyATPxYGoCw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=garling&f=false

Comment: @Suvrit He does call himself Ben though, just in case anyone is wondering if it is that same Garling.

Answer (score 2):

Albert W. Marshall, Ingram Olkin, Barry C. Arnold: ["Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications"](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-68276-1) , second edition, Springer, fits the bill.  They explicitely name the Hardy et al book as an ancestor and inspirator.

The book is based on the concept of majorization and some extension of that, which they say, is literally a "theory of inequalities" and functions as an organizing tool.